# Ack number to acknowledge data in scapy

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

I'm playing around with scapy, trying to do a nmap-like, I succeeded doing a three way handshake and I automatically receive data if I connect to a smtp server but I can't acknowledge it.

I have connected to it via netcat to see why it wouldn't work and nc actually send an ACK packet with the TCP ack field set to the length of the data segment received + 1.
So I am trying to do the same with scapy but I don't know where to find the length of a TCP segment. I tried a lsc(TCP) but I can not see the field.

Here is a wireshark capture of the netcat connection :

[image]

And the detail of the packet :

[image]

As you can see, the ack field of the packet just below the data is 37 + 1 = 38.

Does someone knows where or how it can be found ?

EDIT:

There is actually no field that gives the segment length but it can be calculated with two methods:

```
    tcp_seg_len = len(rp.getlayer(Raw).load)
    # or
    ip_total_len = rp.getlayer(IP).len
    ip_header_len = rp.getlayer(IP).ihl * 32 / 8
    tcp_header_len = rp.getlayer(TCP).dataofs * 32 / 8
    tcp_seg_len = ip_total_len - ip_header_len - tcp_header_len

    ans_ack,unans_ack = sr(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(sport=pkt[1].dport, \
                                          dport=pkt[1].sport, \
                                          seq=rp[1].ack, \
                                          ack=tcp_seg_len + 1, \
                                          flags="A"), \
                           verbose=0, timeout=1)
```

However, when I print the values I get the good ack number but when I watch the wireshark capture, I have a huge ack number and the packet is marked as "ACKed unseen segment". When I look at the bytes in hexa, I got the right value though. Does anyone knows why that happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wireshark uses relative numbers](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/) in its display so the right scapy line is :

```
    ans_ack,unans_ack = sr(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(sport=pkt[1].dport, \
                                      dport=pkt[1].sport, \
                                      seq=rp[1].ack, \
                                      ack=rp[1].seq + tcp_seg_len, \
                                      flags="A"), \
                       verbose=0, timeout=1)
```

And the following code (see EDIT in the question) does work :

```
ip_total_len = rp.getlayer(IP).len
ip_header_len = rp.getlayer(IP).ihl * 32 / 8
tcp_header_len = rp.getlayer(TCP).dataofs * 32 / 8
tcp_seg_len = ip_total_len - ip_header_len - tcp_header_len
ans_ack,unans_ack = sr(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(sport=pkt[1].dport, \
                                      dport=pkt[1].sport, \
                                      seq=rp[1].ack, \
                                      ack=rp[1].seq + tcp_seg_len, \
                                      flags="A"), \
                           verbose=0, timeout=1)
```

Comment: When trying your code snippet, I found that an `int()` is needed for the `tcp_seg_len` which otherwise was a float for me, which unsurprisingly crashed scapy...

Comment: Why do you need all those calculations for the tcp segment length? What you did in the question `tcp_seg_len = len(rp.getlayer(Raw).load)` worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

To get the TCP Segment Length (This has been verified for IPv6 traffic):

```
tcp_header_len = rp.getlayer(TCP).dataofs * 32 / 8
tcp_seg_len = rp.plen - tcp_header_len
```